# How to Set a Buttons Width in Tkinter (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, window

I would like to make a simple quiz program in python 3 but I can not find out how to make a button go the full width I want it to. I am using python 3 and the TKinter module to make the window and all the buttons.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

que_labl = Label(root, text='Question')
choice1 = Button(root, text='Choice one')
choice2 = Button(root, text='Choice one plus one')
choice3 = Button(root, text='Choice 3')
choice4 = Button(root, text='Choice eight divided by 2')

que_labl.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
choice1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
choice2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
choice3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
choice4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

The code makes a window like this:

[image]

Comment: simple google search will give you the correct answer

Comment: Ask yourself "what does `sticky=W` do?"

Answer (score 1):

Use `Grid.rowconfigure()`, `Grid.columnconfigure()` and `sticky=E+W`.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#Configure line 0 and 1
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)

#Configure column 0 and 1
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)

que_labl = Label(root, text='Question')
choice1 = Button(root, text='Choice one')
choice2 = Button(root, text='Choice one plus one')
choice3 = Button(root, text='Choice 3')
choice4 = Button(root, text='Choice eight divided by 2')

que_labl.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
choice1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E+W)
choice2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E+W)
choice3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E+W)
choice4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E+W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: to be pedantic, the sticky value doesn't need to include N and S for this specific question.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you.it was for a table solution.